# Sample size necessary to detect that a mixture distribution is an appropriate model

Tags: mixed-model, mixture-distribution

I am working on an assignment, but having some trouble understanding how I would answer the following:

*"Comment on the shape of the histogram as the sample size increases. Include a description of the sample size that might be necessary to detect that a mixture distribution is an appropriate model for these data."*

I understand the overall concept of mixture distributions, their purpose, and how to create in them in R, however, being able to understand a sample size necessary to detect  that a mixture distribution is appropriate evades me. I understand that this might be different for every. For completeness, here is the entire question, I have all of this coded up and completed, I am just trying to figure out how I should think about this last question. Thanks so much!

Full Question:

[image]

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag. Imho, this is a terribly worded homework!

Comment: Hints: (1) Although this question provides insight about mixtures, it isn't actually about mixtures--it's about testing differences between distributions.  (2) What procedure would you use to decide whether a mixture distribution is appropriate? This ought to have a profound influence on how many observations are needed.  Nevertheless, your plots in 2(f) will be suggestive.  (3) The answer depends a little on what the notation means: are the "3" and "4" parameters in the definitions of the $X_i$ scales or rates?